# How does SuperSu provide root privilege?

Tags: rooting, superuser, selinux

Has a write-up ever been released on exactly how SuperSu works? After searching around for a while I found mostly guides on how to use the app, not the implementation details.

I did, however, find [this](https://su.chainfire.eu/#introduction) resource that is mostly directed at explaining how to use the root privileges programmatically, but explained things fairly well. The article gives information about SELinux, but not so much how its enforcement is circumvented.

There appears to be a lot of context switching to allow execution of certain events (from the point of view of those *using* SuperSu) otherwise denied under SELinux, but how did SuperSu get to the point at which it was able to "*legally*", as far as SELinux is concerned, patch SELpolicies?

It seems that the objective is to force the init process to spawn a new shell that runs the su daemon, but there does not appear to be any patching of the *init* process, but from the article linked:

> On firmwares that use SELinux, su is generally implemented as a proxy to a daemon started from init

and

> You might wonder why - if we're already running as the init context, as the root user ..

---

**tl;dr**; How does SuperSu execute in the context of the init process?

Given as:

```
u:r:init:s0          - Highest init context
u:r:init_shell:s0    - Shell started from init
```

Comment: @AndrewT, SuperSu is the name of the patch to Android that provides root access. The SuperSu APK downloaded from the appstore just manages it from a nice front-end, as you suggest. It, itself, leverages the already-present root accesses to do this, at at least this is how I understand it.

Comment: i don't know exactly, but i can guess that it's merely owned by root:root and have setgid + setuid flags which allows anyone to execute supersu as root - at least that's how i would have implemented it ^^

Comment: @hanshenrik Read **No setuid/setgid programs** and **Restrict Setuid from Android Apps** and **Capability bounding** and **NO_NEW_PRIVS** in [Security Enhancements in Android 4.3](https://source.android.com/security/enhancements/enhancements43)

Answer (score 10):

SuperSU is no more actively developed, the new prevailing standard is Magisk which was originally based on SuperSU (ideas and perhaps some code too) but now it has moved far ahead. So better go for a new actively maintained open-source solution wherever possible. Or if you want some adventure, try this: [How to manually root a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217157/218526).

My answer to [How Magisk works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526) covers almost all internals of SuperSU, also some extra details which aren't applicable to SuperSU. Let's keep it simple.

### ROOT USER (UID `0`):

Android is based on Linux kernel which, when starts at device boot, runs as root user. *Kernel space* is invisible to us - the *userspace*. `init` is the first process started by kernel which we can see, it also runs with root access. It starts many services/daemons (the OS), many of them also run with root privileges. Finally when all required processes are up, `init` drops us to a non-root (unprivileged) process - a *shell* on standard Linux OSes, a *Launcher app* or *Lock Screen* (which is also *System UI* app) on Android. Root is kernel's dear user - the ***Super User*** - identified by **U**ser**ID** `0`. Kernel never restricts him doing any harm or good to anything on device. Non-privileged users are assigned UIDs `1` to `65534` (usually). Android divides these UIDs for different categories of apps and processes as explained [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/libcutils/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h). Every process and every file has a **UID**, **G**roup**ID**, supplementary **groups** and permission **mode**. These four parameters govern how a process accesses other processes and files. This whole phenomenon is called **D**iscretionary **A**ccess **C**ontrol.

### HOW APPS GET ROOT ACCESS?

If an unprivileged process wants to access some file or perform some action which is only allowed to root user, the former has to switch to the latter. It's done by executing a file (usually `su`) which is either [**set-user-id-root**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) or has `setuid`/`segid` **file** [**capabilities**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). A capability is a subset of root user's authorities. Executed file makes [**`setuid`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html) **syscall** so the kernel elevates unprivileged state to privileged. This is a simplification, in actual there are multiple other factors involved. But on Android, apps are run by dropping all capabilities and privileges in such a way that they can't elevate their privileges in any way (excluding vulnerabilities). So the unprivileged app requests some other already running privileged process to perform the privileged task on former's behalf. The privileged process is named `daemonsu` (or `magiskd`) and the request is forwarded when an app executes special `su` binary which interacts with SuperSU app to ask the human user for granting permission.

### SELINUX:

In addition to DAC, Android also makes use of **SELinux** - a **M**andatory **A**ccess **C**ontrol. Like DAC, every process and every file is labeled with a SELinux context and a policy is defined to allow a wide range of [interactions](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-3.18/security/selinux/include/classmap.h) between contexts/labels. Policy contains no ***Super Context***, so every process (even running with UID `0`) has some limitations. But `daemonsu` needs to be run with a completely unrestricted context which has to be defined before SELinux is set `enforcing` (by `init` at very early boot stage) because after that there is no way to set it `permissive` or modify policy. Some vendors build their kernels without `SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP`, so SELinux is enforced by kernel - even earlier. In this case kernel needs to be rebuilt/patched. See details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209374/218526).

### ROOTING PROCESS

When SuperSU.zip is flashed:

- It patches `/sepolicy` file with fully permissive `u:r:supersu:s0` context (`supersu` can be different, I can't recall what SuperSU used in last releases, Magisk now uses `u:r:magisk:s0`).
- It injects a custom `init` service to `/init.rc` file which starts `daemonsu` with UID/GID `0` and SELinux context `u:r:supersu:s0` after `/data` is mounted (or even before).

Both `sepolicy` and `init.rc` files have been part of `ramdisk` inside `boot.img` (which also contains kernel binary), but with Treble, [SAR](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/system-as-root) and `A/B` Partitions they might be on different locations. So Magisk uses different approaches for different devices but the concept is same.

Both steps may also be substituted by replacing the actual `/init` binary with a custom `init` which takes over boot process, patches `sepolicy` and starts service on the go before executing actual `init`.

Other things which are directly related to rooting process include bootloader unlocking, `boot.img` unpacking/repacking, disabling Verified Boot (`dm-verity`) and [FDE/FBE](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/), patching kernel to boot different `init` (or to disable vendor specific security mechanisms), systemless rooting, (un)setting Android properties, bind-mounting directories, isolating mount namespaces etc.