# How does root work in android phones? Does the concept of 'root' exists in android?

Tags: root-access, magisk

So I had an argument with someone over telegram if root exists or not in android.

My point of view is that like any linux kernels the concept of root exists but it's not accessible to other processes. That's where magisk comes in play, hacks the kernel permitting other apps to use the root functionality.

Now the other person mentions that the concept of root doesn't exist in android and mods like magisk implements it.

Now, which one is which? Does root exists in android phones or mods like magisk implement it?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by ***"exists"***. But everything you may want to know about root on Android devices is covered in my answer to: [How Magisk works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526).

Comment: For even more details see [How to manually root a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217157/218526) and [Is there a way to root an Android phone without unlocking the bootloader?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218886/218526) and [How does SuperSu provide root privilege?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217532/218526) and [What special privileges “/system/xbin/su” does have w.r.t. root access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207902/2185260).

Comment: the concept of user root doesn't "exist" on android. in linux world user profile is login user. but android "misuses" user profiles for it's application security concept. each app is another "user" to ensure apps running in "isolated" container and can't harm other apps. on top of this android uses namespace separation and selinux. magisk can deal with all of this and finally provides something what looks like user root, but the magic behind is different from linux (there exist multi user concept on android too but that is quite more confusing in scope of question, parallel apps, work profile)