# What exactly happens after rooting a smartphone?

Tags: rooting

I want to root a tiny cheap smartphone that my 6-year-old grandson uses.

He's a real techie, but he's always changing his password and then forgets to tell me so that I can store it in LastPass. So I want to install a parent protection app, where I'm the Admin, and he's a normal user (as on Windows 10). I already have Kaspersky Safe Kids on the phone, plus he has downloaded a lot of games.

There's no space for a parent protection app, and he's not allowed to use stuff like Chrome, so I want to root the phone to allow me to remove pre-installed stuff.

Here's my question: What exactly happens after rooting?

Is a password still needed for the first login after rooting - because I'm sure he's forgotten it.

Will every app have disappeared? (That would be OK.)

Thanks.

Comment: After rooting, you (means the apps and processes on your device) get the ability to get privileges of UID `0` - the super user or administrator. So the system resources which were not available to you (as a non-privileged user), become available. Now you can do everything; remove prebuilt apps from `/system` partition which you couldn't access before; watch your phone's inside things in more detail, break your phone in a second etc. Password will work as it is, except you will have ability to remove it easily. `Will every app have disappeared?` No, only those you make disappear.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This seems to be an [XY problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154). By removing preinstalled apps you won't gain any additional (user) space – as they are installed on the (read-only) `/system` partition – while the additional space you need would be on `/data`. So for that it is sufficient to *disable* those apps, and then delete their cache and data. That would be all you'd get in free, usable space by uninstalling them anyway. Apart from that: have you seen our [rooting tag-wiki](/tags/rooting/info)?

Comment: rooting is generally not a good idea, thats the opposite of what you want. it is for advanced users only, not for childs

Comment: Oops! I'm now in the embarrassing situation of having to accept only one of the respected posters' responses, because IMHO, they are saying the opposite as far as "bloatware" is concerned. I followed @Izzy link for "rooting tag-wiki". The accepted answer by @ keithjgrant says "If you have a few unnecessary applications (bloatware) pre-installed on your phone that you cannot uninstall, rooting will give you this ability." To step outside StackExchange, I Googled "rooting bloatware". The first two links were "TechRepublic" and "How To Geek"......

Comment: ...They both agree with @ keithjgrant on SE, and therefore with @Irfan Latif. Thanks.

Comment: @OldGrantonian I hope you didn't miss my warning: `Now you can do everything; ...` including `break your phone in a second`

Comment: @OldGrantonian yes, root gives you the ability to uninstall pre-installed apps – but you wouldn't gain additional space by that. And space is what concerns you here. // I could write up an answer for your *real* question, expanding my above comment a bit – but that would answer what you need to know (gaining space), not what you asked here (affects of rooting).

Comment: @irfan. Good warning thanks. I actually don't mind frying a £20 phone that has surprisingly lasted a year and a half. Great opportunity to learn about rooting.

Comment: @OldGrantonian then [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526) could be a good source if you want to learn in a bit depth.

Comment: I re-read all the articles (including link in @Izzy post).
The guys who were linking "bloatware" and "rooting" did not actually say that you gain more space for apps. I apologize for their omissions.

I did a new search: "rooting increases app space". The results mention partitioning an SD. I don't want to create a ball of spaghetti in this thread, so I think I should stop here, and ask a new question regarding partitioning an SD. Or, even better, ask an open question: How to increase space for apps after rooting? Thanks to all.

Comment: @OldGrantonian Good idea. Split it up into "fitting portions". Now that you've got an idea, that should be easier. Note there are already a bunch of questions on how to gain space (root is not necessarily needed), see e.g. what's linked from our [insufficient-memory tag wiki](/tags/insufficient-memory/info) – better check them first, so you can be more specific and thus get better answers. For rooting (and the risks/gains), you already got some pointers. Next to the tag wikis, the "Frequent" tab is also worth checking. Good luck!

Comment: PS: Hope you don't mind I've closed this one here now. Got too confusing (well, started that way – but no "blames" or accusations for that). Let's continue that in specific, dedicated places. Again, wishing the best success in all areas you just discovered :)