# Can't remove bloatware after rooted

Tags: root-access, uninstallation, magisk, bloatware, systemless-root

After my phone is rooted (confirmed by Advanced Root Checker*) using [this tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-root-twrp-3-2-x-galaxy-j2-pro-2018-sm-j250f.3796658/page-3#post-84186563), I can't remove bloatware. Normally this can be done by [System app remover pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp.pro&hl=en&gl=US), but now the removal keeps failing. Do you know why is that?

<sub>*It says that I don't have "Read/Write Path". I don't know what this mean and am not sure if it's relevant here.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to root your device for debloating.
System apps can be "uninstalled" from adb shell

```
adb shell pm disable --user 0 <pkgname>
```

(actually that will disable the app. Do this again after each factory reset)

---

If your device is rooted with Magisk you can remove apps from system (overlay).
Just create some empty files for the file/directory you want remove

```
/data/adb/modules/DEBLOAT/system/app/Bloatware/.replace
/data/adb/modules/DEBLOAT/system/app/Bloatware.apk
```

where DEBLOAT is the id name of your [Magisk module](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/guides.html) and module.prop is the module info

```
/data/adb/modules/DEBLOAT/module.prop

id=DEBLOAT
name=my first module
version=0.0.0 pre alpha
versionCode=000
author=my name
description=just remove some of my system apps
```

If you want you can create a Magisk flashable zip for your module, so you have it handy in case you need it again.

---

Additional explanation quoted from the Magisk Developer Guides:

**Module Tricks**

> **Remove Files**
>
> How to remove a file systemless-ly? To actually make the file *disappear* is complicated (possible, not worth the effort). Replacing it with a dummy file should be good enough! Create an empty file with the same name and place it in the same path within a module, it shall replace your target file with a dummy file.

> **Remove Folders**
>
> Same as mentioned above, actually making the folder *disappear* is not worth the effort. Replacing it with an empty folder should be good enough! A handy trick for module developers is to add the folder you want to remove into the `REPLACE` list within `customize.sh`. If your module doesn’t provide a corresponding folder, it will create an empty folder, and automatically add `.replace` into the empty folder so the dummy folder will properly replace the one in `/system`

Comment: So if I add `system/app/Bloatware.apk` to *any* subfolder in `/data/adb/modules/`, then it will create that file in the corresponding directory?

Comment: yes, assuming core-only-mode is disabled in magisk settings (modules enabled). and (afaik) subfolder **must** contain *module.prop* (untested as i am rooted with SuperSU)

Comment: I still quite confuse. According to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213168/94084), Magisk does not actually replace the file in system with a blank file, but just hide it from being read by other processes, so they only see a blank file, while the real file is left intact. Is that correct?

Comment: yes. the main purpose of this is to keep the whole system partition intact, so that any checksum/ verify of the partition image will be valid

Comment: hmm. I guess I need to root normally then. My intention is to free more storage

Comment: to free up storage disable app and just delete from */data/data/<pkgname>* then (or without root, first clear data from settings and disable app afterwards)