# How may I modify my root filesystem, which is mounted from /dev/block/dm-0, in order to create a mount point or symlink at /usr, on Android 11?

Tags: file-system, mount

I need a writable /usr directory to run Gentoo Prefix. I suppose that it can be either a symlink to somewhere else or a mount point for further mounting.

Information collected so far:

- Since Android 10, remount rw no longer works with root fs.
- Device dm-0 is read-only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't remove bloatware after rooted](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232388)

Comment: Do not modify system on [systemless-root](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/systemless-root/info) method. use magisk module bind mount overlay instead