# Uninstall system apps on rooted android 10

Tags: google-play-store, adb, rooting, root-access

I've been trying to remove the chrome, youtube and playstore applications from my android device, however, I've run into some issues. I've tried rooting my device, but the systems folder is hard-coded as read-only on android 10, so I've not been able to permanently change build.prop or directly uninstall any of these apps. My current workaround has been to remove these apps from my user profile and disable the multiuser feature using the ADB tool. However, when I restart my device, the feature reenables itself. Does anyone know of a better way to approach this problem?

Edit: I've rooted my phone using magisk. Apps like titanium backup have not been able to uninstall these apps.

This is the code that I've used to disable the multisuser feature:
`setprop fw.show_multiuserui 0`
`setprop fw.max_users 1`

Comment: It is the other way around: you have to first root your device and then you are able to remount system partition writeable. Be aware that deleting something from system partition is an easy way to brick your device if you are deleting the wrong file. Why do you want to delete/disable only those apps? E.g. regarding to Google the PlayServices system app does way more than PlayStore.

Comment: Ah okay, so I'll have to mount the system partition. I'll do some research on how to do that. As for the reason, I'm trying to create a distraction free phone for myself, which might be a bit odd, but I find it really nice to not have that constant pull.

Comment: An alternative would be to strengthen your mind to say no to those digital temptations. Also if you don't have a Google account logged in PlayStore app won't work but still install the necessary app updates.

Comment: Flashing a custom ROM might be an alternative since custom ROMs cannot have Google apps packaged together in the first place.

Comment: Find and edit your fstab, look for system partition entry, change/add mount option rw. Also, 'mount -o rw remount <directory>' You might need to invoke through busybox/toybox.

Comment: [(1)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232388) easy method, [(2)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236065) permanent solution