# Root Xiaomi Qin F21 Pro Touch for Android 11

Tags: rooting

How to root [Xiaomi Qin F21 Pro Touch](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Qin-F21-pro-touch-screen-button_1600287560015.html)? (I have the firmware)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219968 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221947

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232388
There is no need to edit system partition. Magisk provides better solution. that's why it is called systemless-root

Answer (score 1):

Unlock [bootloader](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tools-mod-scripts-mlgmxyysds-qin-f21-pro-unlock-tool.4368277), disable [android verified boot](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219968) and root with [systemless-root](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/systemless-root/info) method. If non-unlockable bootloader root with [bootless-root](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/amazing-temp-root-for-mediatek-armv8-2020-08-24.3922213/post-82081703) method.

Comment: i I do not have how to open the bootloader and I want to be able to edit the system partition and in the method that without opening the bootloader it is not possible to edit the system

Answer (score -3):

Press the off button together with call button for about 10 seconds

Comment: The question is about rooting the device. What you have suggested appears to be a key combination to boot into some specific mode in a device, such as fastboot, Recovery, etc.

Comment: Based on the comment on another answer, I'd assume this is a method to unlock the bootloader? Could you [edit] and expand the details on what this button combination is for?

Comment: looks quite promising https://github.com/MlgmXyysd/F21ProInjector https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient#unlock-bootloader https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tools-mod-scripts-mlgmxyysds-qin-f21-pro-unlock-tool.4368277